# "Software selection" step failure during Ubuntu 16.04 server installation

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation, hp

I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 server on a new HPE ML150 hardware. After the installation finishes copying files it prompts for installing additional software.

[image: Software selection]

What ever I choose at this step, the installation reports failure and prompts me to choose which step of installation to continue from.

[image]

Note that I was installing from a USB which I created using Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu desktop.

Looking at the virtual terminal during this step, it seems that it is trying to get the packages from the CD-ROM rather from the internet. I assume that the internet connection works because in a previous step where it tries to figure the timezone by connecting on a timeserver, works fine.

Comment: Please show us the error message too!

Comment: To see the real reason it often helps to switch to the one virtual terminal that contains the logs - try <ALT><LEFT> as often as needed.

Comment: You are right. Tomorrow when I have access to the server. It will a picture though!

Comment: I have added the failing screen of the installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the BusyBox shell
- Change directory to `/target/etc/apt`:

  ```
  cd /target/etc/apt
  ```
- Copy `sources.list.apt-setup` to `sources.list`:

  ```
  cp sources.list.apt-setup sources.list
  ```
- Edit `sources.list`:

  ```
  nano sources.list
  ```

  Comment out the line beginning with `deb cdrom` so it looks like this:

  ```
  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-...
  ```
- Upgrade packages:

  ```
  chroot /target apt-get update
  chroot /target apt-get upgrade
  ```
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to return to the installer, and start *Software Selection*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may answer the question it is not quite clear what those commands do. Please elaborate your answer adding explanations.

Comment: @klaus. As I cannot test this (the server is up and working) I am not able to accept your answer yet. If anyone has this problem and this answer solves it, please comment here so I can accept this answer.

Comment: @Demetris this worked for me. Also, the line to comment out is `deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server...`. One can use ´nano´ to edit the file (ctrk+o to save, ctrl+x to exit).

Comment: I thought I was dead until I tried your solution.  It worked great.  I edited your answer to correct a file name and add the exact commands for newbies, but your answer is pure gold!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I suspect it might be better to  _move_ the `deb cdrom` line to the end of the file rather than deleting it entirely.  This way packages that exist only on the install disk can be found.

Comment: the cp command did not work for me in busybox. Got a "read only file system" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to finish your current installation, see @klaus' superb answer.  If you want to fix the install disk so this no longer happens in future installations:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the BusyBox shell
- View the installation log.  You will be interested in the end of the file:

  ```
  tail -50 /var/log/syslog
  ```

This reveals that when I created the install disk, I removed a required package version:

```
Jul 11 00:42:19 in-target: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
Jul 11 00:42:19 in-target: perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 to be installed
Jul 11 00:42:19 in-target: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
Jul 11 00:42:19 in-target: tasksel: apt-get failed (100):Configuring pkgsel' failed with error code 1
Jul 11 00:42:19 main-memu [2511 WARNING:
Jul 11 00:42:19 main-menu [2511: WARNING: Menu item 'pkgsel' failed with error code 1
```

The installer found the package on the install disk, but it was the wrong version.  Once I corrected this in my install disk creation script, the installation succeeded.